# Create a relationship only if not exist in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to add a relationship between two nodes, but only if the relationship does not exist. For example:

The Relationship between node1 and node2 currently exists with these properties: `time:41221323,link:www.google.com`

I am trying to add a relationship with different properties for example:

```
time:5344241,link:www.google.com
```

In this case i want to keep the original properties on the relationship.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the below CQL query:

> ```
> MATCH(a: startNodeLabel {attributes to match start node})
> MATCH(m:endNodeLabel {attributes to match end node}) 
> MERGE(a)-[:relationshipName]->(m)
> ```

The above merge statement creates relation between nodes a and m if there is no existing relationship between a and m.

Comment: It should be noted that this does create duplicate relationships if the relationship has properties that don't already exist. I recommend adding the line WHERE NOT (a)-[:relationshipName]->(m) before the final MERGE.

Answer (score 5):

You want either the `MERGE` or `CREATE UNIQUE` clause:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-create-unique.html

Also note that `MERGE` comes with additional `ON CREATE SET` and `ON MATCH SET` so you can control when properties get set.

I believe if you give either specific properties as part of the match syntax it will not create only if all of the properties match exactly.

Comment: Note that the CREATE UNIQUE has been removed since Cypher 3.2. Instead, use MERGE.

Comment: For me if there is an `a` with some other relationship other than b and `b` again some relationship other than a, it creates it twice.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

***Create Unique***  clause does serve this purpose. Neo4j Documet says

> CREATE UNIQUE is in the middle of MATCH and CREATE — it will match
>   what it can, and create what is missing. CREATE UNIQUE will always
>   make the least change possible to the graph — if it can use parts of
>   the existing graph, it will.

```
START a=node(...), b=node(...)
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:LIKES]-(b)
return a,b;
```